# How to stage sub-project in Play Activator from bash script?

Tags: bash, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

In my play project I have a separate akka module that I run stand-alone.
If I want to stage this module I usually do the following:

1. `./activator`
2. `project akkaProject`
3. `compile`
4. `stage`

I can stage the main project from a script using `./activator compile && ./activator stage`, but I can't find the correct syntax to do this for a sub-project (without going inside the activator).

Comment: Staging the main project also stages all sub-projects so there actually is no need to stage twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** `activator akkaProject/stage`

You need to scope the `stage` task to `akkaProject` project and since `stage` depends on `compile` you don't need to execute both -- let sbt do it for you.